# Convert HANDLE to Handle

Tags: winapi, haskell, io

I want to create a annonymous pipe on windows using the [`CreatePipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) of the WinAPI via the FFI. This will give me a `HANDLE` (type from the [`Win32`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/Win32-2.3.0.2/doc-index.html) haskell package), but I'd like to get an ordinary haskell `Handle` such that I can use the standard haskell IO functions on it. So I need a function of type:

```
win32handleToStandardHandle :: HANDLE -> IO Handle
```

How can I implement this?

On linux, I can use `System.Posix.IO`'s `fdToHandle` function to convert between the `FD` type used by the linux system calls and the standard haskell type. But there seems to be no such function for windows.

Comment: It looks like `HANDLE` is just a type synonym: `type HANDLE = Ptr ()`. I have no idea how to answer your question but that doesn't give a conversion function much to work with... :\

Comment: I can see that `HANDLE` is defined as `type HANDLE = Ptr ()`, while `Handle` is a an algebraic data type representing either a single handle or a duplex handle for RW, which itself is implemented by a complex record structure.  Are there many functions for getting information about a `HANDLE` from the `Win32` API?  You'll need things like buffering mode, the current char buffer, the text encoding, etc.  It may be possible to write it yourself, but I would imagine it might be somewhat tedious to get correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even on Windows the standard implementation of files in `System.IO` uses a file descriptor, not a win32 `HANDLE`.  These file descriptors are provided by the C runtime, not Windows.  To convert a `HANDLE` to a file descriptor the runtime provides the [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) function.  GHC uses MinGW on Windows but MinGW doesn't provide its own C runtime, so Haskell EXEs use msvcrt.dll.

Use the FFI to import `_open_osfhandle`.  Use this to convert your `HANDLE` to a file descriptor and then call `fdToHandle`, which seems to live in `GHC.IO.Handle.FD`.

I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: MinGW doesn't provide its own C runtime, does it?  Most folk seem to link to the (unsupported!) msvcrt.dll, so the MS docs are as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @HarryJohnston  You're right.  Haskell EXEs import C's standard functions from msvcrt.dll.

Comment: You're right that `fdToHandle` lives in `GHC.IO.Handle.FD`. However, it takes an argument of the type `FD`, which is defined in the non-exposed module `GHC.IO.FD`. But as you say, `HANDLE`'s aren't really supported by the GHC IO functions, so I'll just write the read/write functions directly for `HANDLE`, that's much easier.

Comment: @bennofs  There are two different types called `FD`.  The non-exposed one is somewhat elaborate, but `fdToHandle` is using `System.Posix.Internals.FD` which is just a `CInt`.

Comment: @bennofs: note that every `Handle` has an associated `HANDLE`, because without one the process can't actually do any I/O.  The only difference here is that you want to use a `HANDLE` that you opened yourself rather than one that Haskell (and the C runtime) opened for you.